# No_data_found Exception handling

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
PROCEDURE getEmployeeDetails(EmpID     IN NUMBER,
                             EmpSalary OUT NUMBER) Is
  BEGIN

    SELECT Salary
      into EmpSalary
      FROM Employee_accounts_master
     WHERE Emp_ID = EmpID
       AND SALARY = 'B';

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

      dbms_output.put_line(-20001);
```

When the above query fetches no rows, This procedure throws an NO_DATA_FOUND Exception. Instead of throwing this exception, I need to do some other update/insert process. How to achieve this.

Comment: Renaming this procedure may be advisable, its name ("get employee details") implies that it makes no changes to the database.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just do it in exception section, check the below:

```
Begin
BEGIN

        SELECT Salary
          into EmpSalary
          FROM Employee_accounts_master
         WHERE Emp_ID = EmpID
           AND SALARY = 'B';

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         -- use the label
           goto myinsert;
     end;
    -- here is your line 67 code starts
   <<myinsert>>
    -- your insert statement, for eg.
    insert into emp (empno) values (1);
 end;
```

Comment: is it possible to direct the execution to another line with all the data. Lets say i have an insert operation in line 67. is it possible to shift the execution to line 67 when NO_DATA_FOUND is thrown?

Comment: Why does it take the label as an identifier and asks me to declare it.??

Comment: Have you put the <<myinsert>> before line 67 ?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the code will also attempt to insert if the row is found.  That would be undesirable.

Comment: While I am more relaxed about GOTO than most people, it is still generally regarded as *bad practice*  and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.  This is not one of those rare situations.

Comment: That is why I first suggested to insert the data in exception area of no_data_found.

Answer (score 1):

Testing for the existence of records is one instance where explicit cursors can be useful.

```
PROCEDURE getEmployeeDetails(EmpID     IN NUMBER,
                             EmpSalary OUT NUMBER) 
IS
     cursor c_emp (p_EmpID NUMBER) is
        SELECT Salary
          FROM Employee_accounts_master 
         WHERE Emp_ID = p_EmpID
           AND SALARY = 'B';
     r_Emp c_emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
        open c_emp(EmpID);
        fetch c_emp into r_emp;
        if c_emp%NOTFOUND then
            insert into employee (emp_id) values (EmpID);
        end if;
        close c_emp;
  END;
```

Alternatively you can use a MERGE statement, but just coding a WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT branch.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).